# Inequality on elliptic pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

Let $\Omega=\overline{N(0,1)}$.

Consider linear elliptic pde $au_{xx}+2bu_{xy}+cu_{yy}+r=0$ on $\Omega$, where $a,b,c,r\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ and $ac-b^2\equiv 1$, $\frac{1}{100}<a,b,c<100$.

For all $p<\infty$, is there $C\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ that is a solution to the pde above and $u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ satisfies

$$\|u_{xx}\|_p\le C(\|r\|_\infty+\|u_x\|_\infty+\|u_y\|_\infty)$$

Comment: There is no question here... Please edit your post into a question or else it will be deleted

Comment: Note that posting clarification in the comments is not acceptable.

Comment: @Eddy - Well, that's actually a question, but I edited it to be clear.

Comment: I guess you ask whether there is a $C \gt 0$ such that all $u$ with  $u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$ and *solving the PDE* satisfy such an inequality?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The matrix $A := \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ b & c\end{pmatrix}$ is symmetric and (uniformly) positive definite (why?). Now use elliptic regularity theory.

Comment: -Well, I don't know what theorem can be used, since I'm new to this area.

Comment: Could you give any literature about the theory?

Comment: A standard reference is „Elliptic Partial Differential Equationsof Second Order“ by Gilbarg and Trudinger. However, the results proved there are somewhat more general than what you want to achieve. (Instead of estimates in $L^p$ you get estimates in $C^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in (0, 1)$.) Theorem 6.6 may be a starting point.